# Aggregation of unique rows in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table of unique rows:

```
Name        change  Number_of_Sales
Soby        2.22    8370
Sollerod    -1.06   11287
Sonderborg  2.60    6343
Sonderhald  11.43   1623
Sonderhald  10.93   2098
```

I want to select `name` and `change`, excluding duplicate Names, so that Sonderhald only occurs once. I want the Sonderhald with the maximum `Number_of_Sales`.

How can I do this in SQL Server?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT t.name, t.change, t.number_of_sales
FROM your_table t
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT tt.name, MAX(tt.number_of_sales) AS max_number_of_sales 
        FROM your_table tt 
        GROUP BY tt.name
    ) tm ON t.name = tm.name AND t.number_of_sales = tm.max_number_of_sales
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a common table expression to do this:

```
;
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   Name,
                        Change,
                        Number_of_Sales,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY name ORDER BY number_of_sales DESC ) AS RowNum
               FROM     your_table
             )
    SELECT  Name,
            Change,
            Number_of_Sales
    FROM    cte
    WHERE   RowNum = 1
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx